# Atomicity of field for part numbers

Tags: database, database-design, normalization

In our internal inventory application, we store three values (in separate fields) that become the printed "part number" in this format: PPP-NNNNN-VVVV (P = Prefix, N = Number, V = version).

So for example, if you have a part 010-00001-01 you know it's version 1 of a part of type "010" (which let's say is a printed circuit board).

So, in the process of creating parts engineering wants to group parts together by keeping the "number" component (the middle 5 digits) the same across multiple prefixes like so:

```
001-00040-0001 - Overall assembly
010-00040-0001 - PCB
015-00040-0001 - Schematics
```

This seems problematic and frustrating as it sometimes adds extra meaning to the "number" field (but not consistently since not all parts with the same "number" component are necessarily linked).

Am I being a purist or is this fine? 1NF is awfully vague with regards to atomicity. I think I'm mostly frustrated because of the extra logic to ensure that the next "number" part of the overall part number is valid and available for all prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a number of enterprises that have foundered, or nearly foundered, on the "part number syndrome".  You might be able to find some case studies.  [DEC part numbers](http://www.computertradeexchange.com/inventory/DEC.html) were somewhat mixed up.

The customer is not always right, but the customer is always the customer.

In this case, it sounds to me like engineering is trying to use as single number to model a relationship. I mean the relationship between Overall assembly, PCB, and Scematics.  It's better to model relationships as relations.  It allows you more flexibility down the road.  You may have a hard time selling engineering on this point.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, regardless of database normative rules, when the client/customer/user wants something done a certain way, there is most likely a reason for it, and that reason will save them money (in some fashion).  Sometimes it will save money by reducing steps, by reducing training costs, or simply because That's The Way It's Always Been.  Whatever the reason, eventually you'll end up doing it because they're paying to have it done (unless it violates accounting rules).

In this instance, it sounds like an extra sorting criteria on some queries for reports, and a new 'allocated number' table with an auto-incrementing key.  That doesn't sound too bad to me.  Ask me sometime about the database report a client VP commissioned strictly to cast data in such a fashion as to make a different VP look bad in meetings (not that he told me that up front).